# mysql reporting daily enquiry filtering by type, including missing grouping rows

Tags: mysql

I am a relative newbie and i have been battling with this for too long now - so please can anyone help!

I have a table which receives enquiries(dev_enquiry) for different types of developments and I am creating a dynamic chart to show how many enquiries per day per development. I joined with calendar table which holds a column of dates so that I can get 0 values when there have been no enquiries.

This SQL gives me exactly what I want but its for all the developments

```
SELECT    calendar.datefield AS DATE, COUNT(de_id) AS enquiries
FROM      `calendar`  
LEFT JOIN dev_enquiry ON DATE(dev_enquiry.de_date_created) = calendar.datefield)
WHERE     calendar.datefield BETWEEN (
                                       SELECT MIN(DATE(de_date_created)) 
                                       FROM   dev_enquiry
                                      ) 
      AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(de_date_created)) FROM dev_enquiry)
GROUP BY  DATE 
ORDER BY  DATE DESC

2012-11-08      3
2012-11-07      0
2012-11-06      2
2012-11-05      1
2012-11-04      3
```

**I want to filter out the result by type of development but still  retain the null values when there are no enquiries on that day for that particular development.**

The following filters the result but doesn't give me the null values:

```
SELECT  cal.datefield AS DATE, COUNT(t.de_id)  AS  enquiries
  FROM (
SELECT * FROM dev_enquiry as d LEFT JOIN calendar as c ON (DATE(d.de_date_created) = c.datefield) 
WHERE     d.de_dev_name = 'Green') as t
LEFT JOIN calendar as cal ON (cal.datefield = DATE(t.de_date_created)) 
 WHERE (cal.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT   MIN(DATE(t.de_date_created)) 
FROM dev_enquiry) AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(de_date_created)) FROM dev_enquiry)) 
GROUP BY DATE ORDER BY  DATE  DESC


2012-11-08      1
2012-11-06      2
2012-11-05      1
2012-11-04      1
```

Results for 2012-11-07 are missing

Comment: Nice first question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, by why not just add a `AND de_dev_Name = 'Green'` in your left join in the first query example?

```sql
SELECT    calendar.datefield AS d, COUNT(dev_enquiry.de_id) AS enquiries
FROM      calendar
LEFT JOIN dev_enquiry ON (dev_enquiry.de_date_created = calendar.datefield AND de_dev_name = 'Green')
WHERE     calendar.datefield BETWEEN
          (SELECT MIN(DATE(de_date_created)) FROM dev_enquiry)
      AND (SELECT MAX(DATE(de_date_created)) FROM dev_enquiry)
GROUP BY  d
ORDER BY  d DESC
```

Comment: Brilliant - works a treat - I did try something similar but didn't put in brackets so kept getting errors. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The trick here is to lead your query with the complete calendar table and left join the incomplete (missing some days) summary table. Notice also the `IFNULL` to turn a (null) result into a zero.

```
     SELECT cal.datefield AS date, 
            IFNULL(s.enquiries, 0) AS enquiries
       FROM calendar as cal
  LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT count(*) enquiries,
                  de_date_created
             FROM dev_enquiry
            WHERE de_dev_name = 'Green'
         GROUP BY de_date_created
         ) s on s.de_date_created = cal.datefield
   WHERE cal.datefield 
            BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(de_date_created) FROM dev_enquiry)
                AND (SELECT MAX(de_date_created) FROM dev_enquiry)
   ORDER BY datefield DESC
```

Here's a SQL Fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2db68/12/0

Comment: Hi Ollie - Thanks for quick response and the link. - it works great in the sqlfiddle link but when put into my schema it is repeating multiple date rows rather than adding them up         - might be a mysql thing? thanks again